# Double spend transactions flag the node as "bad"?

Tags: transactions, doublespend, raw-transaction, banscore

I'm playing with raw transactions. It's easy to send two signed valid transactions at the same time from the same output to different addresses (making a double-spend attack). My doubt is: if I make tests like this, will the bitcoin p2p network will flag my node / IP as "bad" or I can do it normally without any consequences? Of course I am not attacking anyone else, I want to make tests with my wallets / system to see the behavior.

Comment: If you want to test things without fear of *real* consequences, you can use the [testnet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Testnet).

Comment: Tip: also have a look at https://github.com/petertodd/replace-by-fee-tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, spending an already spent output is not a DoS banning offense. Sending invalid transactions will however get you banned from your peers.

Answer (score 4):

Your current peers can ban (for some time, not forever) your IP-address.
Just connect to other nodes in case.
The network itself can not do anything with you because there is no such thing in protocol.
Your peers do not know - are you a double-spender or you just relaying somebody's else packets.

(Sorry, my English is also very poor)